# Repo structure for sensitive data

Tags: git, version-control

apologies for the dumb question.

Let's say I'm using Bitbucket to store some code that performs some analysis for a project. The datasets for this analysis are stored in a Sharepoint drive and I'm not allowed to store the datasets on Bitbucket.

What is the best way to structure workflow/the repo to collaborate with other people? We can assume that they also have access to this Sharepoint drive.

Comment: [environment variables](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/what-is-an-environment-variable/) are a common way of handling this

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that environment variables are mainly for credentials? In my case, I'm dealing with several MBs worth of .csv files.

Comment: It can be for anything you'd like to keep out of git.